# Android Studio , some options like 'open an existing android studio project' are not showing and unable to start new project normal way

Tags: android, android-studio

Some options are missing and unable to start a new project.
Don't know what happened.

This is the current view

[image]

This is normal view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting Android Studio default setting.

Go to users[user_name], find folder `.AndroidStudio` and delete it.
This will reset all setting of Android Studio.